# How to control a mechanical part using a button(on/off) on a motorcycle?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

I don't know how to correctly write the question. I have no background knowledge of electronics engineering.

I was wondering for instance, How to open and close the Motorcycle Stand using the On/Off button? Just like the killswitch button or How can we open and close the rearview mirror?

I just want to have an idea. What I would need? How to approach? Parts? I know that I have to configure the ECU unit. But I want to move the mechanical using switches.

Happy to learn.

Comment: Using a spring tensioned construction, one can either "open" or "close" a contraption using a mechanical button. So you have a notch connected to your button that blocks the tensioned arm. if the notch moves away when pressing it, the contraption opens. However, to reverse this action you need some leverage, which just the press of a button doesnt usually deliver. then you need a lever or something.

Answer (score 0):

By your question, **I assume an electrical button**, not a lever where you (as a person) are providing the given force/energy.

Each type of movement has it specific characteristics which make one or another mechanism, better or worse.

---

For example, opening the stand:

- Speed: 90º in few seconds (1-4?)
- Force: High, as it must stand the motocycle
- Max angle: around 100º

Possible solution:
A linear actuator, usually containing some ball-screw, will do the job.

---

Another example, retracting/opening the rearview mirror:

- Speed: 90º in few seconds (1-4?)
- Force: low, as it just need to move the mirror.
- Max angle: around 90º

Possible solution:
A simple servo-motor of some ~20kg/cm should make the job.

---

In both cases, you would need some electronic to control it: micro-controller, driver, battery, etc.

Comment: So, The servo motor is for positioning the part and I have to use Arduino to control the position and angle. Right?

Comment: You don't "need" to use Arduino, but indeed it's an option. You can also buy some pre-constructed electronic. However, I don't think you will find servos strong enough for the stand (Or maybe it can move it to some mechanically locked place)

Comment: Funny enough, the side mirror probably needs to be a LOT stronger than the side stand - high wind velocities for the mirror, and the actuator doesn't have to actually to carry the weight, only extend the stand with no other force applied.

Comment: At 300Km/h, you only have about 40N force on the mirror (100mm x 150mm with Cd=0.6). I agree that you could design the stand (and probably also the mirror) to work with reduced force and relay on it mechanical holding capacity to keep the weight of the bike (or the wind drag).